# Increase MAX array size in Python

Tags: python, arrays, memory-management

I'm, sending several serial requests (get_docs function) and each returns an array of 200000 elements.

Then a extend it with basic array in order to have all data in one array:

```
for iteration in range(0, int(es_request_count)):
  from_value = iteration * 200000
  docs = get_docs(from_value)
  external_ids.extend(docs)
  print "Total array length is " + str(len(external_ids))
```

When I got array size 5400000 **process was killed**.

How to solve this problem ? Do I need to **give process more memory** or if there is a way to **increase max array size** ?

Comment: Python will just keep going until you reach your overall available memory; you don't get to assign it more. Presumably you hit your system limit.

Comment: This is no given limit. Python simply looks for memory. If the memory is exhausted, the operating system will kill the process. Python cannot solve this problem..

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Does it mean my CPU is exhausted ?

Comment: @ВласБоюс: no the memory.

Comment: Why do you need to have all of it in memory at once? If you need to process all of this data, you're going to have to use some approach that does it in batches. Otherwise, start dumping it somewhere on disc.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I meant RAM, sorry

Comment: @ВласБоюс: normally yes. If you look at the machine stats while running it, you will see that your memory will keep increasing until it no longer has any left.

Comment: @roganjosh to send it to a service that compares this array with its internal data

Comment: That doesn't explain why it all has to held in memory at the same time though. If you're not doing something actually _processes_ the data then I can't see any reason why you can't start dumping it to disc